# How to resize and move QGridLayout dynamically to 1/4s

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlayout, qgridlayout

This is my current window layout, I want to have it split up into 1/4, and not 1/2 so to speak.

[image]

This is how I want my window to look, but I can't seem to find a good way to resize the `QGridLayout` to the way I want, and the way `setColumnStretch` works still confuses me and I don't fully understand how it works.

[image]

This is my code for this windows layout:

```py
self.pathRoot = QDir.rootPath()
self.labelFileName = QLabel(self)
self.labelFileName.setText("Search:")
self.labelFileName.resize(100, 30)
self.txtSearch = QLineEdit(self)
self.txtSearch.textChanged.connect(self.on_textChanged)
self.btnBack = QPushButton('Back', self)
self.btnBack.clicked.connect(self.back)
self.model = QFileSystemModel()
self.model.setRootPath(QDir.rootPath())
self.model.setFilter(QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QDir.AllEntries | QDir.Dirs | QDir.Files)
self.proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel(recursiveFilteringEnabled = True, filterRole = QFileSystemModel.FileNameRole)
self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.model)
self.model.setReadOnly(False)
self.model.setNameFilterDisables(False)
self.indexRoot = self.model.index(self.model.rootPath())
self.treeView = QTreeView(self)
self.treeView.setModel(self.proxy_model)
self.adjust_root_index()
self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.indexRoot)
self.treeView.clicked.connect(self.on_treeView_clicked)
self.treeView.doubleClicked.connect(self.treeMedia_doubleClicked)
self.treeView.setAnimated(True)
self.treeView.setIndentation(20)
self.treeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
self.treeView.setDragEnabled(False)
self.treeView.setAcceptDrops(False)
self.treeView.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
self.treeView.setEditTriggers(QTreeView.NoEditTriggers)
self.treeView.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
self.treeView.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.showContextMenu)
for i in range(1, self.treeView.model().columnCount()):
    self.treeView.header().hideSection(i)
self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()
self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.labelFileName, 0, 0)
self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btnBack, 2, 0)
self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.txtSearch, 1, 0)
self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.treeView, 3, 0)
self.gridLayout1 = QGridLayout()
self.progressbar = QProgressBar(self)
self.lblProgress = QLabel('0/0', self)
self.btnClearBatches = QPushButton('Clear Batches', self)
self.btnClearBatches.clicked.connect(self.clear_batches)
self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
self.layout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
self.layout.addLayout(self.gridLayout1)
self.scroll = QScrollArea(self)
self.gridLayout1.addWidget(self.scroll, 0, 0)
self.gridLayout1.addWidget(self.lblProgress, 1, 0)
self.gridLayout1.addWidget(self.progressbar, 2, 0)
self.gridLayout1.addWidget(self.btnClearBatches, 3, 0)
self.scroll.move(7, 80)
self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
self.content = QWidget()
self.scroll.setWidget(self.content)
self.lay = QGridLayout(self.content)
```

Comment: provide a [mre]. I also see that the change of position button, you could explain yourself better, and finally in the piece of code you provide there are other widgets.

Comment: The button, progress bar, can be ignored, I just care about the `QGridLayout`s width on the window, thats the part im stuck on..

Comment: Just for this you need to provide an MRE, and obviously eliminating things that can be ignored.

Comment: What's and MRE?

Comment: MRE: [mre] .....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not necessary to just use QGridLayout to try to build everything, for example to set the stretch factor of the right and left block you can use QWidget as a container. As you do not provide an MRE I have created the design from scratch.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()

    label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Label")
    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button")
    lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

    left_gridlayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
    right_gridlayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

    left_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    left_widget.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(left_widget)
    vbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    vbox.addWidget(label)

    button_and_lineedit_container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    hlay_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(button_and_lineedit_container)
    hlay_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    hlay_2.addWidget(button)
    hlay_2.addWidget(lineedit, stretch=1)
    vbox.addWidget(button_and_lineedit_container)
    bottom_container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    bottom_container.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    bottom_container.setLayout(left_gridlayout)
    vbox.addWidget(bottom_container, stretch=1)

    right_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    right_widget.setLayout(right_gridlayout)

    hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(w)
    hlay.addWidget(left_widget, stretch=1)
    hlay.addWidget(right_widget, stretch=3)

    # debug
    bottom_container.setStyleSheet("background-color:salmon;")
    right_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:gray;")

    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image]